# Passing a query through for an update query PDO using classes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here I am logged in as a certain user (admin) and trying to update another user's group. I am not sure what is not working. I have the sql echo'd out from the DB class to let me see what I am passing through. The sql should be correct and I will put it below.

I will make sure to point out where to look so you aren't searching a lot. And please even if you just have a slight clue of what could be wrong please do share.

Here is the form in which I am trying to update the user. I will post only the relevant php and the form so you can see what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$selectedUser = new User(Input::get('username'));
try {
    $user->update(array(
      'group' => Input::get('group')
    ),'username',$selectedUser->data()->username);

    Session::flash('home','The group has been updated');
    Redirect::to('index.php');

  } catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }



<h3>1: Standard User</h3>
<h3>2: Administrator</h3>
<h3>3: Moderator</h3>
<h3>4: Admin/Mod</h3>
  <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="group">Change Group to</label>
      <input type="number" name="group" id="group">
    <label for="username">for this username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
      <input type="submit" value="Change Group">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
  </form>
```

When I input 2 into the group field and jacob into the username field this is what I receive:

UPDATE users SET group = ? WHERE username = Jacob

There was a problem updating.

This class is really long so I am going to post the relevant material and if something confuses you please just ask and I will specify. If you look at the second method update you can see where I echo out the sql. Here is the DB class:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
      $x = 1;
      if(count($params)){
        foreach($params as $param){
          $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
          $x++;
        }
      }
      if($this->_query->execute()){
        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
      } else {
        $this->_error = true;
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }


public function update($table, $chosenfield, $id, $fields){
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value){
      $set .="{$name} = ?";
      if($x < count($fields)){
        $set .= ', ';
      }
      $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE {$chosenfield} = {$id}";
    echo $sql, '<br>';
    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Here is the last part of the puzzle the user class method that I use in this. This is also where I return the error 'There was a problem updating':

```
public function update($fields = array(), $chosenfield = 'id', $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
      $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $chosenfield, $id, $fields)) {
      throw new Exception('There was a problem updating.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you `var_dump($selectedUser)`  to make sure the constructor is working properly?

Comment: you should also `var_dump(Input::get('group'))` to make sure that is working correctly.

Comment: When I did them both it returned  : Fatal error: Call to undefined function var_dumb() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Registration_Login\admin.php on line 15

Comment: Both of them gave the same error

Comment: lol. it's var_dump, not var_dumb :P

Comment: o jeez lol that is embarrassing haha. var_dump on Input::get('group') 2 gives me back string(1) "2" for input of 2. and var_dump on $selectedUser 'jacob':  the object its a whole lot because of salts and hash.

Comment: if I do var_dump($selectedUser->data()->username);
I just get back the: string(5) "Jacob".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98047/discussion-between-newbiecoder-and-pamblam).

Comment: @Pamblam I moved this to a chat if you would please respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was right in front of me all along, but a little hard to put together since it wasn't clear what connected to what until I saw the full code.

In your `DB::update()` Line 108:

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE {$chosenfield} = {$id}";
// becomes: UPDATE users SET group = ? WHERE username = Humiid2
echo $sql, '<br>';
if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
  return true;
}
```

It looks like you were reading about prepared statements and maybe jumped ahead too soon, because you are creating the query for a prepared statement, but executing it as raw SQL. [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) is for executing raw SQL. Generally, for dealing with user input, you want to use prepared statements instead, which is what you started doing.

Here's what your updated code would look like.

Please reference these functions:

1. [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

This function creates and returns a prepared statement. One way is to replace your variables with `?`.

Example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
```

2. [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

This function binds the parameters to the question marks. You can also do this by passing an array into the `exec()` function. In it's simplest form, it takes 2 parameters. The index of the `?`, (ie 1 for the first ?, 2 for the second, et cetera), and the value to replace it with.

Example:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, 32);
```

3. [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

This function executes the query and returns false if on error. If you use the bindParam function it doesn't take any parameters.

Example

```
$success = $stmt->execute();
```

So, your updated code for your `update()` method might look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE {$chosenfield} = ?";

// Create the prepared statement
$stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);

// Bind each parameter
for($i=0; $i<count($fields); $i++)
    $stmt->bindParam($i+1, $fields[$i]);

// Copy the last one
$stmt->bindParam($i+1, $id);

// The execute call tells whether or not the query was successful
if($stmt->execute()){
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Handy tip: execute already returns a boolean, so you can save yourself a couple of lines by just returning the execute call.

```
return $stmt->execute();
```